# How to Save Repository Live Data in a View Model

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

Howdy everyone hope all is well and swell, so I am having an issue with storing the live data I retrieve from my repository into my view Model so that my fragment can observe it. The scenario is as follows:
I have a suspended repository call like this

```
suspend fun getProfiles(profileId: Int): Resource<LiveData<List<Profile>>?> 
{
    return if(profileCaching()){
        Resource.success(profileDao.getProfiles())
    }else {
        val result = fetchProfilesDataSource(profileId)//Suspend func API call
        when (result.status) {
            Status.SUCCESS -> when (result.data) {
                null -> Resource.noContent()
                else -> Resource.success(profileDao.getProfiles())
            }
            Status.LOADING -> Resource.loading(null)
            Status.ERROR -> Resource.error(result.message!!, null)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is trying to structure my view Model so that a copy of this can be saved on it (To be observed by a fragment). I have tried calling it directly like this
`val profiles = repo.getProfiles(10)` 
, but because it is suspended I have to wrap it in a viewModelScope. Additionally, I have tried using MediatorLiveData to try the copy the live data, but it didn't seem to retrieve it

```
var source: MediatorLiveData<List<Profile>> = MediatorLiveData()

fun processProfiles(){
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        val results = repo.getProfiles(10)
        if (results.status == Status.SUCCESS && results.data != null) {
            source.addSource(results.data, Observer{
               source.value = it
            })
        } else {
            //Set the empty list or error live data to true
        }
    }
}
```

Wanted to know if I was doing something wrong, or should I try a different approach?

Comment: It is better to remove `LiveData` from repository. Please follow this article https://proandroiddev.com/no-more-livedata-in-your-repository-there-are-better-options-25a7557b0730

Comment: And I can see that you have already return a `LiveData<List<Profile>>` from a DAO. You do not want to return a `LiveData` from the repository. And furthermore, you are returning a Result based object from the repository. If you want to return a Result based object from the repository you should not use a `LiveData` in DAO at all. Just use a normal Kotlin coroutines.